# Is there a way to change different namepaces in one calss in C#?

Tags: c#

[image]

My quesiton is How is it possible to inherit CriclesApplication.Circle inside DisplayClac class?
//namespaces are different.

DisplayCalc.CS

```
namespace MathShapesProject.Shapes
{
    class DisplayCalc : CirclesApplication.Circle
    {
    }
}
```

Circle.CS

```
namespace CirclesApplication
{
    public class Circle
    {//the rest of the class
    }
}
```

...

I tried this
[image: it did not work]

Comment: would you please elaborate your question

Comment: What you have **should** work. The error is indicating that you don't have a parameterless constructor in `Circle` class.

Comment: You need to either add a parameterless constructor in `Circle` or more likely a constructor in `DisplayCalc` that calls a defined constructor of `Circle`.

Comment: @GrantWinney I think the OP is not showing the constructors for brevity.  That's the only explanation for the message.

Comment: here is my explanation of displaycalc.Cs ...I understand inheritance as if it could inheritance everything from one class to another. my mini project is to include all the shapes and inherit the display calculations,(displaycalc.Cs) for each mathematical shape in dispalyclac.cs. I just wanted to make the code look neat,  editable and readable by using inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with namespaces.  The issue is that `Circle` does not have a parameterless constructor.  So you either add a parameterless constructor to `Circle` or more likely a constructor in `DisplayCalc` that calls one of the `Circle` constructors.

Let's assume that `Circle` has this constructor.

```
pubic Circle(Point center, int radius) { }
```

Then in `DisplayCalc` you'd need something like.

```
public DisplayCalc(Point center, int radius) : base (center, radius) { }
```

Although you might want to ask yourself if `DisplayCalc` should inherit from `Circle` in the first place.  Just based on the names it doesn't sound like `DisplayCalc` is a type of `Circle`.

Comment: Thank you very much +juharr and to those who tried to help